# Passing MongoTemplate to Custom Repository implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Project is configured to used multiple **MongoTemplate** s

Mongo Ref is passed as

```
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages={"com.mypackage.one"}, mongoTemplateRef="mongoTemplateOne")
```

for repositories in the package `com.mypackage.one`

and

```
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages={"com.mypackage.two"}, mongoTemplateRef="mongoTemplateTwo")
```

for repositories in the package `com.mypackage.two`

For standard repositories it works fine. But for the scenarios, where I need custom behavior, I define say **myRepoCustomImpl** with my custom behavior needs.

**Problem**: I need to have access to the **MongoTemplate** which the the analogous standard Repository.

e.g. 
If `MyRepo` is extending `MyRepoCustom` interface as

```
@Repository
interface MyRepo extends MongoRepository<MyEntity, String>, MyRepoCustom{}
```

**MyRepoCustomImpl**

```
@Service
    public class MyRepoCustomImpl implements MyRepoCustom{
        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("mongoTemplateOne")
        MongoTemplate mongoTmpl;

        @Override
        MyEntity myCustomNeedFunc(String arg){
            // MyImplemenation goes here
        }

}
```

If **MyRepo** is in package `com.mypackage.one`, the `mongoTemplateOne` will be used by myRepo, so there should be a some way to MyRepoCustomImpl will know that it should also use **mongoTemplateOne**, whenever I will make change in the `mongoTemplateRef` for `MyRepo`, say as

```
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages={"com.mypackage.one"}, mongoTemplateRef="mongoTemplateThree")
```

now I need to make changes to @Qualifier in the `MyRepoCustomImpl`!
There are lots of repos with custom behaviour, so its becoming tedious task.

**Question:** Instead isn't there any way that the MongoTemplate to be used should get automatically injected or resolved according to the Repo it is extending to?

Comment: The only thing additional you can do is to have a base class and initialize the MongoTemplate with the respective qualifier and make that variable Protected.

Answer (score 1):

`MongoTemplate` isn't exposed by the `MongoRepository` interface.  They could potentially expose the name of the `MongoTemplate` `@Bean` and that could provide a solution to your question. However, given the fact that they don't, I will provide an example below that may suit your needs.

First off `mongoTemplateRef` refers to the *name* of the `@Bean` to use, it doesn't specify the name of the `MongoTemplate`.

You will need to provide each `MongoTemplate` `@Bean` and then refer to it within your `@EnableMongoRepositories` annotation.

Since you are using spring-boot you can take advantage of the `MongoDataAutoConfiguration` class.  Please take a look at what it does here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.java.

The simplest example is this.

**package:** com.xyz.repo (this implementation relies on the configuration provided by `MongoDataAutoConfiguration`)

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages={"com.xyz.repo"}) //mongoTemplateRef defaults to mongoTemplate
public class XyzRepoConfiguration {

}

public abstract class BaseRepo {
    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
}

@Service
public class MyRepoCustomImpl extends BaseRepo implements MyRepoCustom {    
    @Override
    MyEntity myCustomNeedFunc(String arg){
        // access to this.mongoTemplate is present
    }
}
```

**package:** com.abc.repo

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages={"com.abc.repo"}, mongoTemplateRef=AbcRepConfiguration.TEMPLATE_NAME)
public class AbcRepoConfiguration {
    public static final String TEMPLATE_NAME = "mongoTemplateTwo";

    @Bean(name="mongoPropertiesTwo")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.data.mongodb2")
    public MongoProperties mongoProperties() {
        return new MongoProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name="mongoDbFactoryTwo")
    public SimpleMongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory(MongoClient mongo, @Qualifier("mongoPropertiesTwo") MongoProperties mongoProperties) throws Exception {
        String database = this.mongoProperties.getMongoClientDatabase();
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongo, database);
    }

    @Bean(name=AbcRepoConfiguration.TEMPLATE_NAME)
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(@Qualifier("mongoDbFactoryTwo") MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory, MongoConverter converter) throws UnknownHostException {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory, converter);
    }
}

public abstract class BaseRepo {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(AbcRepoConfiguration.TEMPLATE_NAME)
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
}

@Service
public class MyRepoCustomImpl extends BaseRepo implements MyRepoCustom {    
    @Override
    MyEntity myCustomNeedFunc(String arg){
        // access to this.mongoTemplate is present
    }
}
```

**com.xyz.repo** will rely on `spring.data.mongodb` properties within `application.properties`
**com.abc.repo** will rely on `spring.data.mongodb2` properties within `application.properties`

I haven't used the AbcRepoConfiguration.TEMPLATE_NAME approach before, but it was compiling within my IDE.

Please let me know if you need any clarification.

Answer (score 1):

`MongoTemplate` is not injected on your repository class but deeper in `spring-data-mongodb` so you cannot get it from your repository. Look at the code you will learn a lot of stuff.

So no you can't inject a bean according to the repo extend except if you disable spring-boot auto-configuration and component discovery and configure it by your self but it will be much longer than just changing `@Qualifier` name. Your IDE call help you easily and you might regret disable auto-configuration.

Sorry for the disappointment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following example.

1)

```
package com.johnathanmarksmith.mongodb.example;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

/**
 * Date:   6/28/13 / 10:40 AM
 * Author: Johnathan Mark Smith
 * Email:  john@johnathanmarksmith.com
 * <p/>
 * Comments:
 *  This main really does not have to be here but I just wanted to add something for the demo..
 *
 */


public class MongoDBApp {

    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MongoDBApp.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("Fongo Demo application");

        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MongoConfiguration.class);




        logger.info("Fongo Demo application");
    }
}
```

2)

```
package com.johnathanmarksmith.mongodb.example;

import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractMongoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;

import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * Date:   5/24/13 / 8:05 AM
 * Author: Johnathan Mark Smith
 * Email:  john@johnathanmarksmith.com
 * <p/>
 * Comments:
 * <p/>
 * This is a example on how to setup a database with Spring's Java Configuration (JavaConfig) style.
 * <p/>
 * As you can see from the code below this is easy and a lot better then using the old style of XML files.
 * <p/>
 * T
 */

@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {MongoDBApp.class})
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {


    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "demo";
    }



    @Override
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
        /**
         *
         * this is for a single db
         */

        // return new Mongo();


        /**
         *
         * This is for a relset of db's
         */

        return new Mongo(new ArrayList<ServerAddress>() {{ add(new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27017)); add(new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27027)); add(new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27037)); }});

    }

    @Override
    protected String getMappingBasePackage() {
        return "com.johnathanmarksmith.mongodb.example.domain";
    }

}
```

3)

```
package com.johnathanmarksmith.mongodb.example.repository;


import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.johnathanmarksmith.mongodb.example.domain.Person;


/**
 * Date:   6/26/13 / 1:22 PM
 * Author: Johnathan Mark Smith
 * Email:  john@johnathanmarksmith.com
 * <p/>
 * Comments:
 * <p/>
 * This is my Person Repository
 */


@Repository
public class PersonRepository {

    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonRepository.class);

    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public long countUnderAge() {
        List<Person> results = null;

        Query query = new Query();
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria = criteria.and("age").lte(21);

        query.addCriteria(criteria);
        //results = mongoTemplate.find(query, Person.class);
        long count = this.mongoTemplate.count(query, Person.class);

        logger.info("Total number of under age in database: {}", count);
        return count;
    }

    /**
     * This will count how many Person Objects I have
     */
    public long countAllPersons() {
        // findAll().size() approach is very inefficient, since it returns the whole documents
        // List<Person> results = mongoTemplate.findAll(Person.class);

        long total = this.mongoTemplate.count(null, Person.class);
        logger.info("Total number in database: {}", total);

        return total;
    }

    /**
     * This will install a new Person object with my
     * name and random age
     */
    public void insertPersonWithNameJohnathan(double age) {
        Person p = new Person("Johnathan", (int) age);

        mongoTemplate.insert(p);
    }

    /**
     * this will create a {@link Person} collection if the collection does not already exists
     */
    public void createPersonCollection() {
        if (!mongoTemplate.collectionExists(Person.class)) {
            mongoTemplate.createCollection(Person.class);
        }
    }

    /**
     * this will drop the {@link Person} collection if the collection does already exists
     */
    public void dropPersonCollection() {
        if (mongoTemplate.collectionExists(Person.class)) {
            mongoTemplate.dropCollection(Person.class);
        }
    }
}
```

4)

```
package com.johnathanmarksmith.mongodb.example.domain;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

/**
 * Date:   6/26/13 / 1:21 PM
 * Author: Johnathan Mark Smith
 * Email:  john@johnathanmarksmith.com
 * <p/>
 * Comments:
 * <p/>
 * This is a Person object that I am going to be using for my demo
 */


@Document
public class Person {

    @Id
    private String personId;

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getPersonId() {
        return personId;
    }

    public void setPersonId(final String personId) {
        this.personId = personId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(final int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [id=" + personId + ", name=" + name
                + ", age=" + age + "]";
    }

}
```

https://github.com/JohnathanMarkSmith/spring-fongo-demo

Answer (score -1):

You can directly inject MongoTemplate and MongoOperations in your service classes.

Try to auto-wire them and then you should be good.

Update:

Without autowiring with proper qualifier(since you have two repositories) this is not possible. As Custom class all together different from repository. If you had only one repository then autowire of mongotemplate would have been sufficient otherwise you have to provide the qualifier in impl as two beans of MongoTempalte are created.

Comment: I need to have access to the MongoTemplate which the the standard Repository? you have a problem in custom or standard?

Comment: Can you please provide more information like what have you tried. What i have understand from your question is you can access the custom method using repo and you want to access it using mongoTemplate? or you are not able to access to mongoTemplate after custom implmentation? Please clear my doubts so that we can assist.

Comment: @Mr.Arjun did you able to find the answer you are looking for?

Comment: Not yet, that's why put a bounty on that!

Comment: Basically, you are saying that MyRepoCustomImpl doesn't uses mongoTemplateOne what you have defined during EnableMongoRepository? and you will have to inject mongoTemplateOne using Qualifier inorder to use that template. right?